# Is Esperanto language's pronunciation systematic?

Tags: pronunciation

I mean, Is the alphabet and pronunciation correspond to each other?

Comment: Yes, they are. You can pronounce any word if you know the few rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each letter has only one sound. There are no silent letters.

Here is a good link for you regarding the Esperanto alphabet and sounds of the letters. http://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/skribo

Comment: To be technical, there is a bit of allophonic variation in Esperanto. For example, the two N’s of daNkoN are usually pronounced differently ([ŋ] and [n]). But such variation exists in all languages, and it does not ”diminish” the simplicity of the Esperanto spelling system, IMHO. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to your question is:

**Yes.**